# Reproducing ST Design Gate Driver

Tags: bjt, dc-dc-converter, level-shifting, gate-driving, totem-pole

I try to reproduce the buck-boost converter from the "STM32F334 Discovery" board.
Therefore I have drawn a KiCad Schematic and assigned the appropriate spice models.
But unfortunately, I'm not able to reproduce the behavior. Or at least I think so, because the gate p-fet (P1) is in my opinion not properly driven.

[image]
Picture form STM UM1735 Fig. 13

[image]
KiCad schematic of the gate drive circuit.
A 1n capacitor is added as gate equivalent.

[image]
The waveform at the "gate-caps"

I think something went wrong or I have a misunderstanding of the design.
For my own purposes, I would like to drive the Ubatt form 3.0-4.2V 3.7 nominal.
The logic level *_Drive may be at 3.3V but I would prefer 2.5V.

Because the p-fet from the reference design is not available, there could be some parameters to change for the p-fet (Vgs threshold).

Comment: Next step would be looking at the other voltages around T6,T8. Looks to me like T6 may be incorrectly fitted, or damaged, R53 incorrect value, or Vbatt not constant.

Comment: This is all simulation only, therefore nothing should be damaged.
Vbatt is constant as you can see in the plot.

Answer (score 0):

(Given the comments it needs a different explanation. This stays until OP sees everything, then I'll either delete it or add a new answer.)

Comment: This is no bootstrap circuit, because a p-fet is used.
The capacitor in the original circuit is to decouple the push-pull amplifier.
The capacitor in my schematic is used to represent the gate of a mosfet.
I do not include the decoupling capacitor because my voltage source is ideal.

Comment: @Stain It doesn't matter what type the switch is, the capacitor's purpose is to provide an energy reservoir for the level shifter made with the totem pole; or a bootstrap. At any rate, if your voltage source is ideal then you don't need the additional circuitry. If it helps, [here](https://hub.wsu.edu/aerospace/2019/03/15/4-switches-buck-boost-converter/) is the functionality of a 4-switch buck-boost.

Comment: @a concerned citizen Therefore I didn't have the capacitor included. The capacitor in my schematic is used as a "MOSFETs gate equivalent" for simulation only, I need "something" to charge to observe the behavior.
My main question is "Why is the voltage decreasing overtime on P1?".
Because the initial voltage difference would be fine, but the later development is to low.

Comment: I can not see any energy storage except the capacitor, which could influence the voltage over time. Therefore I do not get why the voltage at P1 is decreasing over time.

Comment: @Stain A quick run in LTspice doesn't show any droop: [test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXqFZ.png). Is there anything else connected after `P1` or `P2`?

Comment: No, there is nothing more connected to it. But you used a different model of the transistor, may be that the reason?

Comment: @Stain That's the only one that comes close to what you have there and exists in the default library. I don't know if that's the cause, it seems unlikely, but you can probe the voltage at the drain and see if it's constant.